# Query All Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Im trying to build a query that get all rows in datastore,but my problem is that i have hundreds of rows and when i try to run one time,i almost get limits quotas..
So my question is,what im doing wrong?

```
Query query = new Query(myObject);
 PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
 QueryResultList<Entity> results = pq.asQueryResultList(fetchOptions);
 resp.setContentType("text/plain");
 resp.getWriter().println(results.size());
 for (Entity entity : results) {
  resp.getWriter().println("entity.getProperty("name")");
```

Comment: You need to provide more details.  Which quota, do you have billing enabled, are you getting a deadline exceeded. What do you plan to do with all the entities is your example contrived or real. Looking at the code you are just printing the name, have you trued a projection query ..

Comment: what you mean by "you almost get limits quotas"... you mean having the 0.05M daily read operation quota spent?

Comment: yes,i have quota free...

Answer (score 1):

What you have wrong is your algorithm. You cant do that with many rows since your frontend will timeout.
Look at task queues and backends.